# ocaml batteries compiling : Unbound module Toploop

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-batteries

```
**Build mode: shared
ocamlbuild -no-links syntax.otarget byte.otarget src/batteries_help.cmo META shared.otarget

Finished, 0 targets (0 cached) in 00:00:00.

+ ocamlfind ocamlc -c -g -annot -warn-error A -package camomile,num,str -package camlp4.lib -pp camlp4of -pp camlp4of -I libs/estring -I benchsuite -I src -I testsuite -I build -I qtest -I libs -I src/syntax/pa_comprehension -I src/syntax/pa_strings -o libs/estring/pa_estring_top.cmo 
libs/estring/pa_estring_top.ml

File "libs/estring/pa_estring_top.ml", line 18, characters 15-44:

Error: Unbound module Toploop

Command exited with code 2.**


Compilation unsuccessful after building 6 targets (5 cached) in 00:00:00.**
```

I have found toploop.cmi in path:

```
cd OCaml/lib/ocaml/compiler-libs/
ls topl*

toploop.cmi
```

and as you see,

```
export PATH=/home/xxx/OCaml/lib/ocaml/compiler-libs/:$PATH
```

I have made `/home/xxx/...` as my system path. But it still did not work. What I should do to include the module toploop?

Comment: thanks a lot for your edit. I am a new flower. I will pay my attention to the format in my future questions. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be compiling Batteries (which version?) with OCaml 4.00, which introduced the new `compiler-libs` directory (but some distributions had one before so that may be off). `toploop` used to be at the root of the OCaml stdlib's directory, but you should now add a `-I +compiler-libs` option somewhere, or use the corresponding ocamlfind packaging (`-package compiler-libs.toplevel`).

Comment: the version of Batteries is 1.4.1. The system has two versions of OCaml which are 3.09 and 4.00. The 3.09 one is at /usr/.. and the other is at /home/xxx/OCaml. I do not have the authority to install it at the /usr/... path.

Comment: File "libs/estring/pa_estring_top.ml", line 18, characters 15-44:. The pa_estring_top.ml code is here:

Comment: let _ =
  let parse = !Toploop.parse_toplevel_phrase and lexbufs = ref [] in
  Toploop.parse_toplevel_phrase :=                                                                                                    
~

Comment: I have just realized that I can edit the command line by myself and make it run instead of autorun. Thanks a lot. The error is correct. But there is one other problem waiting for me.