# ocaml batteries compiling:ERROR: Leftover OCaml compilation files:

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-batteries

```
Build mode: shared
ocamlbuild -no-links syntax.otarget byte.otarget src/batteries_help.cmo META shared.otarget
Finished, 0 targets (0 cached) in 00:00:00.
SANITIZE: a total of 3 files that should probably not be in your source tree
  has been found. A script shell file
  "/home/fanzhihang/batteries-1.4.1/_build/sanitize.sh" is being created.
  Check this script and run it to remove unwanted files or use other options
  (such as defining hygiene exceptions or using the -no-hygiene option).
Warning: Leftover OCaml type annotation files:
  File pa_estring_top.annot in libs/estring has suffix .annot
IMPORTANT: I cannot work with leftover compiled files.
ERROR: Leftover OCaml compilation files:
  File pa_estring_top.cmo in libs/estring has suffix .cmo
  File pa_estring_top.cmi in libs/estring has suffix .cmi
Exiting due to hygiene violations.
Compilation unsuccessful after building 0 targets (0 cached) in 00:00:02.
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

This compiling error of batteries really puzzles me. How should I fix the error?

Answer (score 1):

Do you know [OPAM](http://opam.ocamlpro.com/) ?

```
$ opam install batteries
```

It will install all dependencies automatically.

**[EDIT]**
How to install opam:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/OCamlPro/opam
$ ./configure # (or ./configure --prefix=$HOME if you want to install under your $HOME)
$ make
$ make install
$ opam init
$ eval `opam config -env`
```

Comment: can I fix the installed path if I install batteries by it? I do not have the root authority.

Comment: installed OPAM follow the tutorial here: http://opam.ocamlpro.com/doc/Quick_Install.html[link]              ./opam64:/lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.7' not found (required by ./opam64)`code`

Comment: You don't need to be root. Try to compile opam from source [here](https://github.com/OCamlPro/opam) and re-try `opam install batteries`. I'll edit my post for the opam install part.

Comment: You should definitely use `./configure --prefix=$HOME`

Comment: opam init
Cannot download http://opam.ocamlpro.com/urls.txt, please check your connection settings.
'opam init' failed `code`  How should I check my connection settings?

Comment: Do you have `~/.opam` directory ?

Comment: Check this [issue](https://github.com/OCamlPro/opam/issues/288), maybe it could help.

Comment: the author said my curl version should be update. But I have try another tool software named godi which helps me install batteries successfully. Thanks a lot. Your PhD study is quite interesting:)

Answer (score 0):

You can execute the script:

```
/home/fanzhihang/batteries-1.4.1/_build/sanitize.sh
```

This will delete the files that OCamlbuild thinks should not be here (namely the .annot, the .cmo and the .cmi the error is talking about).

Comment: it does work and it removes some files installed not correctly. But I do roll back to the problem:Unbound module Toploop. You can my question here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13506800/ocaml-batteries-compiling-unbound-module-toploop