# ocaml batteries installation

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-batteries

There seems to be conflicting information about batteries installation. I have tried several suggestions, but none have worked for me.

I first tried

```
ocamlfind batteries/ocaml
```

but that gave this error:

```
ocamlfind: Cannot find command: /username/godi/lib/ocaml/pkg-lib/batteries/ocaml
```

I then tried copying the ocamlinit file from the batteries directory to .ocamlinit in my home directory. This gave this error:

```
Cannot find file topfind.
File ".ocamlinit", line 38, characters 0-20:
Error: Unbound module Toploop
```

I am using ocaml 4.00.1.

Note: I apologize if this question is redundant with this one [ocaml batteries compiling : Unbound module Toploop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13506800/ocaml-batteries-compiling-unbound-module-toploop) but the answer given was not explicit enough for me to actually try.

Comment: A bit unrelated but you should dump GODI asap and use opam: https://github.com/OCamlPro/opam once you have opam running then a simple `opam install batteries` should make everything work.

Answer (score 4):

Like @rgrinberg said, try to install batteries with opam. For that, first download the quick installer:

```
$ wget http://www.ocamlpro.com/pub/opam_installer.sh
```

Then execute this script:

```
$ sh ./opam_installer.sh /usr/local/bin
```

It will install the latest "stable" opam (you can of course change the path `/usr/local/bin`) and the latest version of the OCaml compiler.

After that, you just need to run:

```
$ opam install batteries
```

and it should be ok.

You can also check [ocaml.org](http://ocaml.org/install.html) install section (by package manager) or [opam website](http://opam.ocamlpro.com/).

Comment: Thanks - the installation works, but I'm still having trouble getting batteries to run in the top level. I get "unbound module Toploop" when I try ocamlfind batteries/ocaml.

Comment: OK you juste need to set some variable environment, see my answer in this [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14751914/opam-package-not-running/14752071#14752071)

Comment: Ah - sorry. In the meantime, I had just installed batteries from source, and that went fine.